# What do I do about a caravan that is being attacked?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

So, in order to get money in Assassin's Creed 3 you've got to send out caravans (or naval caravans) to ship your goods across the lands and all that Jazz. Well when the game was first explaining this they had me send out a single caravan to an area just as demonstration. However, now this Caravan is apparently under attack and has been for quite some time. The menu has no options or anything of the sort to give me ways to deal with this, and the caravan just sits there in the menu being completely useless. What do I need to do with this caravan in order to get it out of its "attacked" state and usable again?

Comment: Sounds like you should go to the mission waypoint to start a mission. This is similar to the tower defense game, where you had to defend it, if your notarity was escalted beyond "Level 2" ( i.e. Wide Red Circle ) in Brotherhood ( ACII x 3 ).

Comment: Revelations, not Brotherhood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caravans under attack are always located in the Frontier.  Head there and you'll see a shield icon on the map - that's your caravan:

[image: screenshot]

Get there, help fend off the Redcoats, and you're good.

Comment: Strange. I have my caravan attacked for a very long time. I see no mission on the frontier to defend it, and it still hasn't disappeared. What to do in this case? Is this a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

When your convoy is attacked you have about six or so minutes to get to it after that it will disappear as it has been destroyed.

I think you only defend your convey in the frontier but I can't be sure (edit: I looked up and I guess I was right.) Anyway, I think you have run into a glitch that disables your convoy.  It says that it is being attacked however it is nowhere to be found in the frontier.

As of 12/29/12 there is no known fix for this glitch and we will have to wait for a patch from Ubisoft.  I have run into this glitch and it is pain as it can potentially cut a 1/3 out of your income.

Answer (score 1):

So once your caravan has been attacked, you need to defend it in the frontier. It will be marked by a sheild icon, and you must kill the redcoats there. When it happened to me, I didn't know this unfortunately. And the same thing happened to me; it remained unusable. But, I also found a way to fix it.

At the accounting book (within the manor at homestead), you can craft another caravan. Cheaply. First, go to your stock pile. You should see a list with categories on the right, and one of them will be labeled "forest." Buy 1 oak lumber and 1 oak bark, and then go to the crafting menu.

You will see something that says recipies. Press it, and it will lead you to another list. Go to the category that says "special items." From there, if you scroll right, you will eventually find an item that says land convoy. Craft it, and the problem is fixed!

(Edit: Oh, lol! This is from 4 years ago? Sorry! But I hope you find this useful anyways!)

Comment: Hey, welcome to Arqade! Don't worry about the fact that you answered a 4 year old question, this answer looks great.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Nah, sorry! Solution did NOT work! Just completed sequence 12 as well as all Assassin Recruit Missions. Attacked convoy is still stuck!

---

> I have read about a *solution* for this [Convoy status stuck at "Attacked" glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/93752/58622) somewhere.
>
> What you need to do is [Spoiler]:
>
> > Complete all the [Assassin Recruit Missions](http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-3/Assassin_Recruit_Missions) - this should unlock an extra convoy, as well as remove the "Attacked" status of the stuck convoy.
>
> I have not yet tested the solution, but it seems legit. I'm nearly there now and will post my findings when complete.