# How do I acquire more convoys?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

In *Assassin's Creed 3*, you have the option of sending out convoys loaded with goods for sale.

I'm lead to believe that this should be your primary means of income as you roam the frontier and kill defenseless animals for the sake of profit. [I've seen this question about what to do when a convoy is under attack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91840/what-do-i-do-about-a-caravan-that-is-being-attacked), but it doesn't indicate what to do *after the fact*.

Unfortunately, I was unable to make it to my convoy in time to prevent the attack, and now my convoy is completely lost. A look at my ledger shows that I currently have *no* convoys available. This has put me in a bit of a financial bind.

**How can I get more convoys if, and when, I lose the one(s) I currently have?**

Comment: Not an answer but I found that convoys felt like a waste of time. The ship convoys seemed to be more profitable (especially with the low risk once you'd done the naval missions) since the value of items seemed very high when selling that way but the land convoys seemed to be not that much return on investment (price of sale not much more than price of production). I found hunting and skinning (getting perfect pelts of course) to be a much better way to make money but it may be because I enjoyed hunting animals.

Comment: @Chris Don't you have to convoy to sell those pelts? Or can I just go to any store?

Comment: any store will buy them direct. Though no idea of the difference in profits by convoying them vs selling direct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build more convoys once you get access the the estate ledger.

At the accounting book , you can craft another caravan. Cheaply. First, go to your stock pile. You should see a list with categories on the right, and one of them will be labeled "forest." Buy 1 oak lumber and 1 oak bark, and then go to the crafting menu.

You will see something that says recipies. Press it, and it will lead you to another list. Go to the category that says "special items." From there, if you scroll right, you will eventually find an item that says land convoy. Then, just craft it.

You can have a maximum of three convoys at any time.

Comment: You also build the naval convoys this way though I'm not 100% sure when they open up (I suspect I didn't see them for some time). I suspect it may just be when you get access to naval stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to make another convoy. Just go to the guy that's taking care of you, and he will help you with supplies and a few men, but the rest would be on your own.

Comment: "with supplies and a few men" what?  Also Achilles only sets you up with your first convoy.  If it gets destroyed you have to build another..