# My convoy's status is stuck at "attacked", what can I do?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

My convoy has been attacked and i sent my mini-mes to deal with it. Strangely, they became available nearly instantly, despite the dialogue saying they would be occupied for 11 minutes. I don't remember any other announcements since then, my other convoys have made 2 trips already but the attacked convoy is still in limbo. I've checked the Frontier but the convoy defense icon isn't there. Can I get my convoy back in the game?

Comment: "I've checked the Frontier but the convoy defense icon isn't there"  Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I have a convoy which is also stuck in 'Attacked'. I tried crafting a new one to be told my inventory is full. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Having the same problems with my attacked convoy stuck in limbo. Just curious if anyone has had more then1 convoy stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as Ubisoft does not release a patch: No, you won't get it back. It is a known bug, at least for the community, Ubi does not seem to care too much.

I lost mine when a convoy was attacked and I closed the game instead of trying to save it. Next time I started the game, the convoy was still under attack, but no way to save it.

Edit: Does not seem like Ubi would patch it soon. The [Holiday Patch](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/739410-Assassin-s-Creed-III-Holiday-Patch-Spoilers-Forums) from Dec 18 fixes numerous bugs, but not the Convoy bug – which is listed already on the second page (of currently 101) in their [official bugs thread](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/720981-Assassin-s-Creed-3-Single-Player-Bugs-and-Issues-Thread-*Possible-Spoilers*).

Edit 2: Neither did Patch 1.03 fix this bug.

Edit 3: Patch 1.06? lol. As if they cared.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug for sure. I have a full inventory of convoys and they're fully upgraded. I know how to defend them myself if attacked or how to send my assassin recruits in my stead. I make a lot of money off the convoys, although I've quickly run out of things to buy or use them for, and I use them often.

When one of my convoys got the bug, I received a notification saying it was being attacked. I was busy doing something else at the time, and honestly, I didn't want to go through that tiring routine of saving it myself — though it shouldn't have gotten attacked in the first place, as I'd already removed the risks of an attack.

I sent a couple of my assassins. Later on, I received a notification saying they were successful in saving the convoy, that the convoy reached home, and that I received my money. However, when I checked the accounting book, it still said "Attacked." I've searched for any answers in the net, and I found that a lot of gamers experienced the bug too, and that no fix or patch was available. Furthermore, I found out that the full use of all convoys was required in a trophy or achievement, which means the bug messed up more parts of the game than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Nah, sorry! Solution did NOT work! Just completed sequence 12 as well as all Assassin Recruit Missions. Attacked convoy is still stuck!

---

> I believe there is a *solution* for this glitch. I posted the answer [over here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/138269/58622) and quoted below.
>
> > I have read about a *solution* for this Convoy status stuck at "Attacked" glitch somewhere.
> >
> > What you need to do is [Spoiler]:
> >
> > > Complete all the [Assassin Recruit Missions](http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-3/Assassin_Recruit_Missions) - this should unlock an extra convoy, as well as remove the "Attacked" status of the stuck convoy.
>
> I have not yet tested the solution, but it seems legit. I'm nearly there now and will post my findings when complete.